# How to vertically align multiple radio button columns in Shiny R?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

---

I would like to create a list of radiobuttons inside a tabItem in Shiny.  If I set inline = TRUE, it puts everything on horizontal lines, but nothing is lined up neatly.  How would I vertically align the radio buttons in the following code, while defining the number of columns I want?

```
        # Descriptive Plots tab content
    tabItem(tabName = 'descrPlots',
            fluidRow(
              column(width = 2,
                     box(
                       width = NULL, background = "aqua",
                       radioButtons('radio_Descr',label = h3("Choose a Variable to View:"),
                                    choices = list('TA' = 'TA','PP' = 'PP', 'US' = 'US', 'UD' = 'UD', 'UE' = 'UE',
                                                   'UG' = 'UG', 'UH' = 'UH', 'XR' = 'XR', 'RW' = 'RW', 'PA' = 'PA', 'TB4' = 'TB4',
                                                   'TV2' = 'TV2', 'TV4' = 'TV4', 'TV8' = 'TV8', 'TV20' = 'TV20', 'TV40' = 'TV40', 
                                                   'MV2' = 'MV2', 'MV4' = 'MV4', 'MV8' = 'MV8', 'MV20' = 'MV20', 'MV40' = 'MV40',
                                                   'VB' = 'VB', 'TA40' = 'TA40', 'TA120' = 'TA120', 'SD' = 'SD'), inline = TRUE, selected = NULL)
                       
                     )
              )
            )
    )
```

I would think I could wrap the radio buttons in a tagList like the following, but what is the code I need to actually get it to work?  I am not an HTML or CSS programmer, and can't follow other questions dealing with this very well.  All this code is, so far, in the UI part of the Shiny app, not the server part.  Maybe that should be changed, too?  Thank you.

```
       box(
          width = NULL, background = "aqua",
            tagList(
                    tags$style(type = 'text/css', '#radiobuttons .multicol{-webkit-column-count: 2; 
                                 -moz-column-count: 2; column-count: 2;}'), 
                    div(id = 'radiobuttons',
                          radioButtons('radio_Descr',label =
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Think the easiest way ist to use the bootstrap css for this. What we can do is to add the classes for columns and rows just in the sameway as we do when we use the `fluidRow` and 'column' in shiny. For example a `column(width = 2)` is actually just a `div` with the `class=col-md-2`.

We can use jquery to add these classes to the radio buttons with the javascript code `$('.radio-inline').addClass('col-md-3');` to make thise work properly we need to add the class `row` to the parent tag `$('.shiny-options-group').addClass('row');` To do this in shiny we add the following code **after** the radio button

```
  tags$script("$('.radio-inline').addClass('col-md-3');$('.shiny-options-group').addClass('row');"),
```

To make it look really nice we need to set `margin-left:10px` to the first radio button as well, by defualt is only added to 2:nd and following buttons. We can do this by inserting this code

```
tags$head(
    tags$style(
      ".radio-inline{margin-left:10px;"
    )
  )
```

That should do it.